# Android - Insert one image into another's transparent pixels

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap

In Android, I'm attempting to layer two images (In this case, Bitmap objects) in a FrameLayout. One image is placed on top, with the other image inserted below it at that image's first transparent pixel.

Currently, I'm attempting the following using `Bitmap.getPixel()` to locate the transparent pixel:

```
for (int i = 0; i < image_count; i++)
{
    //load page from internal memory
    topImages[i] = getImage("p"+i+".png");
    for (int x = 0; x < topImages[i].getWidth(); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < topImages[i].getHeight(); y++)
        {
            if (topImages[i].getPixel(x, y) == Color.TRANSPARENT)
            {
                bottomX[i] = x;
                bottomY[i] = y;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I then add the images to a Frame Layout, using two ImageViews, and use these values to position the lower image:

```
bottomView.setTranslationX(bottomX[position]);
bottomView.setTranslationY(bottomY[position]);
```

However, the placement of the bottom image is always inaccurate, usually by a margin down and to the right that is different (but always the same) for each given image. I've also tried `setX()` and `setY()`, as well as using parameters to set the `TOP` and `LEFT` values similarly, with the same results). What can I do to ensure that the placement is always consistent, with the image's `top-left` at (or close to) the first transparent pixel?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only display the images, you can add them as different frames in FrameLayout. In your xml, first declare the one you want to show as transparent pixels, then declare the one which will have transparent pixels.

Comment: Do you mean that the FrameLayout has a way to automatically position my image in the transparent area? To clarify, they are already layered; what I need is to be able to center the image in the transparent area. Edit: I also need to do this automatically, with sets of images from a server, so I can't manually setup each layout.

Comment: @user3732383 As the images have transparent area, they will be in png format. If you put them in an imageview, it will show the area behind imageview through transparent areas. So, you can take different imageviews in a frame and stack them. If the count of images is dynamic, you can inflate ImageViews dynamically in the layout.

Comment: Oh! Yes. I'm already able to properly place one image on top of the other. That part works fine. What I'm trying to do is make the horizontal and vertical (x and y) position of the bottom image automatically line up with the first transparent pixel of whatever top image is chosen. The result would be that the top-left corner of the bottom image goes where the transparent area of the top image begins.